# How to structure routes in react router v6, to show layouts properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently I've a layout like this (note: I'm using [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router))

- `"/"` only contains top nav bar (root layout) (its content is blank)
- `"/home"` home page/landing page (with root layout + content: Using [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet))
- `"/otherpages"` other pages (with root layout)

The problem is the content on main/root route (`"/"`) there is nothing/blank and only contains nav bar, this is not what I want. I want to show home page here with nav bar in place too, but on the root location (`"/"`). So it is nav bar as layout PLUS home page as content but this homepage will be replaced by other outlets on routing.

Comment: Home page and other pages are children of root "/" so homepage = site.com/homepage
and other pages = site.com/otherpage. site.com = NavBar + blank content